# insert multiple rows with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I need to `insert` multiple rows for current column in a table.

sql

```
insert into pa
(cd)
values
((select 'SU' from pa where pa_id = 101))
 ;
```

What is the correct syntax? Getting error, cannot insert null value.

Comment: how many columns in PA?  You are only supplying value for 1 column.  The error indicates you have other columns, with not-null constraints, that you are not supplying a value for.  Please update your question to provide the CREATE TABLE for PA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want an `update` instead:

```
update pa
    set cd = 'SU'
    where pa_id = 101;
```

`insert` inserts a new row.  All the columns not included in the `insert` are set to `NULL` -- which is no doubt causing your error.

You seem to want to change the value in an existing row; `update` does that.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into pa (cd)
select 'SU' 
from pa
where pa_id = 101
```